# Updating the database

Tags: android, database

Welcome.
Database updated in this way:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        Log.e("TAG", "New database version exists for upgrade.");

        try {
            Log.e("TAG", "Copying database...");
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that I have a table in the database of statistics, I wanted to order the data in this table are copied into the new database.

How do I? Ask for an example.

Regards and sorry for my poor English.

---

I tried to do this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        Log.e("TAG", "New database version exists for upgrade.");

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            Log.e("TAG", "Copying database...");
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            ArrayList<Statystyka> statystyki = getAllStatistic();
            copyDataBase();
            for (int i = 0; statystyki.size() >= i; i++) {
                addStat(statystyki.get(i).getId_pytania(),
                        statystyki.get(i).getIlosc_rozwiazan(), statystyki
                                .get(i).getIlosc_poprawnych(), statystyki
                                .get(i).getIlosc_blednych());
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.endTransaction();
    }

}
```

But I get the error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getReadableDatabase called recursively

How do I open the database to load the data?

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade of database, old tables are still there you just need to change to the new schema version. see [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29).

for eg::
say you have to add a new column to your table ::

```
String alter_table_command=" ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + NEW_COLUMN + " TEXT; ";
db.execSQL( alter_table_command );
```

Read about ALTER TABLE [here](http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).

NOTE:: In the case you want to copy a table from another database then use the solution as suggested by @vipul above.

Comment: I already know how to add a new column, and now populate the new table as the old data?

Answer (score 0):

onUpgrade does not create a new database. It just gives you the opportunity to create new columns or tables, or to update the data in the database in some way to make it compatible with the new version.

Thus, you should not need to be copying any data into a new database.